# Can Mac app store apps access local file system?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I am wondering what limitations are imposed on the Mac app store.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  For instance, lets say I wanted to write an app that does incremental auto-backups of files on the Mac file system, is that possible with an app in the Mac app store, or would my only option be a standalone mac app?

On the iPhone, apps are self contained in their own "sandbox"? Does this same principal apply to mac app store apps?

Comment: No clue what your question is.  Yes, Apps can read/write from disk.  Yes, they have sandboxing of sorts, ie. you can't delete the filesystem without admin rights.  What does this have to do with auto-backups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that starting in November, Mac App Store submissions must adopt the App Sandbox. There are specific entitlements that you can request when your app is submitted to the app store, along with an explanation of why you need those entitlements. More information can be found in WWDC Session 204 video on the Developer site.

Comment: Apple will require sandboxing on March 1, 2012.

Comment: Sandbox requirement was extended to June 1, 2012

Answer (score 9):

Fellows, what the OP is really referring to is described here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

It is all about

- Containers
- Entitlements
- PowerBox (daemon)

Once an application is "sandboxed" its view of the ~ "home" directory is that of a Container (which happens to be created upon first start in $HOME/Library/Containers/appBundleID/Data). Therein it finds its "private copy" of config, cache and data files. And off course it can't read anything else, unless...

... you give the application the appropriate Entitlements in the form of a codesign-ed property file (in fact, codesigning is integral part of the sandboxing concept).

One of these Entitlements is the "**com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write**" which **allows the application to read and write exactly those files which the user has explicitly chosen via the standard save and open dialog respectively**.

The PowerBox (pboxd) daemon then renders the appropriate file dialog in its own process space and adds the selected file paths to the list of allowed files. This is transparent to the application, that is no code changes are required - as long as the application uses the standard NSOpenPanel or NSSavePanel dialogs.

"To facilitate application sandboxing, Mac OS X v10.7 provides a trusted system daemon that is tasked with presenting open and save panels on behalf of applications running in an application sandbox. That daemon is called Powerbox (its process name is pboxd). These Powerbox-presented remote panels appear fully indistinguishable from in-process panels in terms of user experience.

Any time an application running inside a sandbox invokes an NSOpenPanel or NSSavePanel dialog, rather than showing the panels directly, AppKit automatically asks the Powerbox to present the dialog. From a developer perspective, there are no code changes required in terms of how these panels are used; this process is fully transparent." [end quote from Apple docs]

Given all that, **what the OP would need (for a backup solution) are "unmediated read/writes"**:

"If an application chooses to derive the user's home directory in a way that bypasses Cocoa APIs (by directly invoking getpwent, for example), the application sandbox prohibits it from writing to the paths it receives (unless the application has the unmediated write entitlement, which is strongly discouraged for obvious security reasons." [end quote from Apple docs]

However the closest Entitlements which would give "free access to the file system" I could fine would be:

"

- **Absolute file read-only**—The ability to read the files or directories at the specified absolute paths. (**com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only**)
- **Absolute file read/write**—The ability to read or write the files or directories at the specified absolute paths. (**com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write**)

" [end quote from Apple docs]

And I am not sure whether an application could simply provide the root directory "/"

Anyway, **carefully note that these entitlements are marked "temporary": Apple might remove/deprecate those entitlements at seen fit**!

Answer (score 2):

The are changing or have changed with the Lion release. Mac Store apps used to be able to do anything within the filesystem that the logged in user privs could allow but I think you are now required to use the entitlements system and hence sandbox your App.

Read this for more ideas

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572

Comment: I did not understand his question as "I want to do a Time Machine", but "I want to do an application that may read/save any file, even created by another app".

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there is sandboxing on the OS X.  However, applicants started manually by the user bypass those sandboxing restrictions (sometimes requiring escalation / admin verification screens).

Take a look at:
http://techjournal.318.com/security/a-brief-introduction-to-mac-os-x-sandbox-technology/

Comment: This applies to the sandboxing technology prior to Mac OS X Lion; the app sandbox technology is substantially extended in Lion, which is what the questioner is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

This will help. Take a good look at it.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16

Answer (score 0):

You can currently find Hype or Pixelmator on the Mac App Store.

This proves evidently that you can save to disk and read from disk, which seems a basic feature of any serious application. Moreover, Apple is pushing developers to start using incremental auto-backups of files, it would therefore be very surprising if they forbade that in the App Store, wouldn't it?